# OL outside of DIV

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create an OL but for some reason, which is probably very basic, this OL doesnt appear within the Blue Div.  Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/6AkFR/

Comment: After reading the answers/comments, you possibly want this: `ol { padding: 0 } ol li { list-style-type: decimal; list-style-position: inside; }`

Comment: @thirtydot yes its always something simple. Here is the finished product: http://www.davincispainting.com/colorselector.aspx    I owe alot of great thanks to @Neal for his help as well.

Comment: the jsfiddle link gives a 404

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to have the numbering on the `ol`:

```
ol {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

ol li {
    list-style-type: decimal; /* or 'decimal-leading-zero', 'upper-alpha', 'lower-alpha'... */
    list-style-position: outside; /* or 'inside' */
    margin-left: 1em; /* gives 'room' for the numbers to appear in */
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AkFR/5/).

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck the `"Normalized CSS"` checkbox in jsFiddle....

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6AkFR/1/

Comment: @Sime OK, it works in JSFiddle, but what do I need to change in my html page? And why is there so much left padding?

Comment: @Paul What do you want to achieve on your page? By default, browsers define a left padding on OL and UL elements.

Comment: @Sime, I would just like to have normal numbering within the Blue Div without that unecessary left padding.  I didnt know that left padding was defined by default.

Comment: @Paul You don't have normal numbering on your page? By default, the numbering should be present, so you must have disabled it in your CSS code (or you use a CSS Reset that did it).

Comment: @Sime normal numbering? in which html tag? well this is an .aspx page

Comment: @Paul If you have an OL element on your page and that element contains LI elements, then - by default - the LI's will be numbered.

Comment: @Sime yea the numbering worked fine, the problem was the placement within the DIV, maybe I will just make images ...

Comment: @Paul You mean the padding? You can use the `padding` CSS property to set the padding of the OL element manually. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/6AkFR/6/

Comment: @Sime yes that was exactly my problem! Thank you
!